# 90s/early 2000s comic featuring a little imp named Charlee and his adventures on another planet

Tags: story-identification, comics

Looking for a comic from the 90s or early 2000s featuring a little imp named Charlee and his adventures with a tortoise friend. They visit another planet or the moon, where there are many angels, and have various adventures. The drawings were kind of realistic, and I read a two-color edition in an Indian magazine. Can anyone help me identify the name of this comic or provide more information about the series and its characters?